# Getting a Runtime Error NZEC on Problem Code on HS08TEST (Python 2.7

Tags: python

Title basically says everything
Code link: https://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST

```
words = input()
x = words.split(' ')
withdraw = float(x[0])
init = float(x[1])

if(withdraw%5==0 and init>withdraw):
    final=init-withdraw-0.5
    print(final)
elif(init<(withdraw+0.5) or withdraw%5!=0):
    print(init)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1
    30 120
         ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: You could be more clear about the error you are receiving. This code runs for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a Runtime Error NZEC on Problem Code on HS08TEST (Python 2.7.13)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67002632/getting-a-runtime-error-nzec-on-problem-code-on-hs08test-python-2-7-13)